# Python: how to use Python to generate a random sparse symmetric matrix?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

How to use python to generate a random sparse symmetric matrix ?

In MATLAB, we have a function "[sprandsym (size, density)](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/matlab/ref/sprandsym.html)"

But how to do that in Python?

Comment: Is this a numpy matrix or just nested arrays? If you're trying to emulate matlab, numpy and scipy are a good team, as unutbu notes

Answer (score 6):

If you have scipy, you could use [sparse.random](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.random.html). The `sprandsym` function below generates a sparse random matrix X, takes its upper triangular half, and adds its transpose to itself to form a symmetric matrix. Since this doubles the diagonal values, the diagonals are subtracted once.

The non-zero values are normally distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation
of 1.  The Kolomogorov-Smirnov test is used to check that the non-zero values is
consistent with a drawing from a normal distribution, and a histogram and
QQ-plot is generated too to visualize the distribution.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed((3,14159))

def sprandsym(n, density):
    rvs = stats.norm().rvs
    X = sparse.random(n, n, density=density, data_rvs=rvs)
    upper_X = sparse.triu(X) 
    result = upper_X + upper_X.T - sparse.diags(X.diagonal())
    return result

M = sprandsym(5000, 0.01)
print(repr(M))
# <5000x5000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
#   with 249909 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

# check that the matrix is symmetric. The difference should have no non-zero elements
assert (M - M.T).nnz == 0

statistic, pval = stats.kstest(M.data, 'norm')
# The null hypothesis is that M.data was drawn from a normal distribution.
# A small p-value (say, below 0.05) would indicate reason to reject the null hypothesis.
# Since `pval` below is > 0.05, kstest gives no reason to reject the hypothesis
# that M.data is normally distributed.
print(statistic, pval)
# 0.0015998040114 0.544538788914

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
ax[0].hist(M.data, normed=True, bins=50)
stats.probplot(M.data, dist='norm', plot=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

PS. I used

```
upper_X = sparse.triu(X) 
result = upper_X + upper_X.T - sparse.diags(X.diagonal())
```

instead of

```
 result = (X + X.T)/2.0
```

because I could not convince myself that the non-zero elements in `(X + X.T)/2.0` have the right distribution. First, if `X` were dense and normally distributed with mean 0 and variance 1, i.e. `N(0, 1)`, then `(X + X.T)/2.0` would be `N(0, 1/2)`. Certainly we could fix this by using

```
 result = (X + X.T)/sqrt(2.0)
```

instead. Then `result` would be `N(0, 1)`. But there is yet another problem: If `X` is sparse, then at nonzero locations, `X + X.T` would often be a normally distributed random variable plus zero. Dividing by `sqrt(2.0)` will squash the normal distribution closer to 0 giving you a more tightly spiked distribution. As `X` becomes sparser, this may be less and less like a normal distribution.

Since I didn't know what distribution `(X + X.T)/sqrt(2.0)` generates, I opted for copying the upper triangular half of `X` (thus repeating what I know to be normally distributed non-zero values).

Comment: Thx but miss 'symmetric' property.

Comment: How can we make such that diagonal elements must be non-zero ?

Comment: Apart from missing the symetric propery, the values of `scipy.sparse.rand` are uniformlly distributed, whereas those of `sprandsym` are normally distributed

Comment: @hipoglucido: Thanks for pointing that out. I've update the answer to make the result symmetric with values from a normal distribution.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix needs to be symmetric too, which seems to be glossed over by the two answers here;

```
def sparseSym(rank, density=0.01, format='coo', dtype=None, random_state=None):
  density = density / (2.0 - 1.0/rank)
  A = scipy.sparse.rand(rank, rank, density=density, format=format, dtype=dtype, random_state=random_state)
  return (A + A.transpose())/2
```

This will create a sparse matrix, and then adds it's transpose to itself to make it symmetric.

It takes into account the fact that the density will increase as you add the two together, and the fact that there is no additional increase in density from the diagonal terms.

Comment: Here, I need all non-diagonal elements to be non-zero and the maximum number of non-zero values are given. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

unutbu's answer is the best one for performance and extensibility - numpy and scipy, together, have a lot of the functionality from matlab.

If you can't use them for whatever reason, or you're looking for a pure python solution, you could try

```
from random import randgauss, randint
sparse = [ [0 for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
# alternatively, if you have numpy but not scipy:
# sparse = numpy.zeros(N,N)
for _ in range(num_terms):
    (i,j) = (randint(0,n),randint(0,n))
    x = randgauss(0,1)
    sparse[i][j] = x
    sparse[j][i] = x
```

Although it might give you a little more control than unutbu's solution, you should expect it to be significantly slower; scipy is a dependency you probably don't want to avoid