# Generating random sparse positive semi-definite matrices in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I wan to create random test instances for some piece of code, which relies on sparse positive semi-definite matrices.

Matlab has the function sprandsym(n,density,rc), which creates random sparse symmetric matrices with eigenvalues rc, so a nonnegative vector rc leads to a PSD matrix.

Is there a way to recreate this function in python?

I found various solutions to either create a random sparse matrix or a random PSD matrix. I also found a solution for the combination of both by creating a random sparse matrix and, if it is not PSD, adding the identity matrix until it is PSD (namely the absolute value of the smallest eigenvalue times). But this solution creates diagonally dominant matrices, which unfortunately is not sufficient for my needed test instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26895137/3562088) which relys on `scipy` and `numpy` and should give you what you need:

```
def sprandsym(n, density):
    rvs = stats.norm().rvs
    X = sparse.random(n, n, density=density, data_rvs=rvs)
    upper_X = sparse.triu(X) 
    result = upper_X + upper_X.T - sparse.diags(X.diagonal())
    return result
```

Comment: I saw that answer, but that function does not ensure that the produced matrix is positive semi-definite, does it?

Comment: Ah I see! In the future you should include the resources that you already found yourself to your question. Otherwise it is really difficult to know what a good starting point for an answer would be. I would encourage you to post a new question where you specify what you have already found and tried and what else you need.