# How to generate a Random Sparse Hermitian Matrix in python?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I would like to generate a **Random Sparse Hermitian Matrix** of a given shape in python. How can I do it efficiently? Is there any built-in python function for this task?

I have found a solution for the random sparse matrix, but I want the matrix to be Hermitian too. Here is the solution for the random sparse matrix that I found

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed((3,14159))

def sprandsym(n, density):
    rvs = stats.norm().rvs
    X = sparse.random(n, n, density=density, data_rvs=rvs)
    upper_X = sparse.triu(X) 
    result = upper_X + upper_X.T - sparse.diags(X.diagonal())
    return result

M = sprandsym(5000, 0.01)
print(repr(M))
# <5000x5000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
#   with 249909 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

# check that the matrix is symmetric. The difference should have no non-zero elements
assert (M - M.T).nnz == 0

statistic, pval = stats.kstest(M.data, 'norm')
# The null hypothesis is that M.data was drawn from a normal distribution.
# A small p-value (say, below 0.05) would indicate reason to reject the null hypothesis.
# Since `pval` below is > 0.05, kstest gives no reason to reject the hypothesis
# that M.data is normally distributed.
print(statistic, pval)
# 0.0015998040114 0.544538788914

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
ax[0].hist(M.data, normed=True, bins=50)
stats.probplot(M.data, dist='norm', plot=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Show us your solution.

Comment: I have found a solution in this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895011/python-how-to-use-python-to-generate-a-random-sparse-symmetric-matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that a matrix plus it's hermitian is a hermitian matrix. So to ensure your final matrix `B` is hermitian, just do

```
B = A + A.conj().T
```

Comment: Ahh. That's a nice solution. I never thought in that way. Thank you so much.